# Expand out the product $(x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2)(x^2 + 2xy + 2y^2)$. Use the result to determine all pairs of integers $n,m$ s.t. $n^4+4m^4$ is prime.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

just a bit stuck on this one..here is what I have so far:

Let $p = (x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2)(x^2 + 2xy + 2y^2) = x^4+4y^4$, where $p$ is a prime number.

so, either $(x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2)$ or $(x^2 + 2xy + 2y^2) $ must be 1.

Assume $(x^2 + 2xy + 2y^2) = 1 $ then,

$p = (x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2) = x^2 - 2y(x-y)$

so, I have that  $ x\neq{y}$ and $ y\neq{0} $, since that would mean $x^2 = p$.

I also have that $x$ must be odd and $4y^4$ must be even since $p$ is prime. But now I am stuck, not sure where to go from here..

Am I on the right track? The question is a little confusing to me, because it tells me to expand the expression, but all the middle terms just cancel out - so I am not too sure what to do with it?

Many thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$(x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2)(x^2 + 2xy + 2y^2)=((x^2+2y^2)-2xy)((x^2+2y^2)+2xy)\\
=(x^2+2y^2)^2-(2xy)^2=x^4+4y^2$$
A necessary condition for that $n^4+4m^4$ is prime is 
$$n^2-2nm+2m^2= 1\iff(n-m)^2+m^2=1\\\iff (n,m)\in\{(1,0),(1,1),(-1,-1),(-1,0)\}$$
or
$$n^2+2nm+2m^2= 1\iff(n+m)^2+m^2=1\\\iff (n,m)\in\{(-1,1),(1,-1),(1,0),(-1,0)\}$$
and we verify that the sufficient condition is valid for $$(n,m)\in\{(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1)\}$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$1:$  Set $x^2-2xy+2y^2=1\implies (x-y)^2+y^2=1$

So, either $(x-y)^2=0,y^2=1$ or vice versa

$2:$ If we set $x^2+2xy+2y^2=1\implies (x+y)^2+y^2=1$

So, either $(x+y)^2=0,y^2=1$ or vice versa